# iOS 5 now encrypts my text message backup?

Tags: ios, messages, encryption, sqlite

I've always used MesaSQLite to open the SQLite database that stores my iPhone's text messages. I've also used python's sqlite3 module to programmatically do some things with my text messages.

After I upgraded to iOS 5, however, now when I try to open it up in MesaSQLite I get prompted for an encryption key, and my programs fail saying that the database is encrypted. I have my iPhone (it's an iPhone 4) set to backup to my computer and to not encrypt my backup, but it still is. Does this have something to do with iMessage (since it's advertised as "secure and encrypted")? Is there any way to find out what the encryption key is?

Comment: No but software like PhoneView can get you those messages as a separate data store ith iOS 4 and 5 whether encrypted or not.

Comment: Okay, but if PhoneView can do it in software, that means I can too, right?

Comment: Of course - they key are stored in the keychain infrastructure so you just need to learn how to program that and interface with either [IO kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOKitLib_h/index.html) or [IOUSBDeviceInterface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205145/programming-a-usb-device-on-a-mac). The [ecamm devs](http://stackoverflow.com/users/205032/ken-aspeslagh) are very sharp, so it might take you longer then 8 years to build what they have, but in software it's the coder that matters - not so much the task.